# reading chunked response body

Tags: java, http, chunked-encoding

I am trying to make a proxy server which caches request and response. 
For response header which says transfer-encode: chunked

How do I allocate memory for this type of response ? 
I tried using byte[chunksize] and reading the chunk, but the size is characters and not bytes.

Also please help me how can I send the normal response body in this format.

Resources: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: The chunk should be bytes.

Comment: I tried reading with bytes, but after reading the first chunk, I didn't get the position of next chunk size. Am I doing it right ?

Comment: `\r\n` at the end of a chunk is not included in the count.

Comment: `\r\n` right after the number is not included in the count as well.

Comment: Thanks, I shall work on it and reply back with my work.